# Why BOM is U+FE FF, rather than U+FF FE?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

So I'm teaching myself character encoding, and I have a presumably stupid question: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) says

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF BYTE ORDER
>   MARK (BOM), ...

, and a chart on that page writes

```
Encoding      Representation (hexadecimal)  
UTF-8         EF BB BF  
UTF-16 (BE)   FE FF  
UTF-16 (LE)   FF FE  
...
```

I'm a little confused by it. As I know, most machines using Intel CPUs are little-endian, so why BOM is `U+FE FF` for UTF-16 (BE), rather than `U+EF BB BF` for UTF-8 or `U+FF FE` for UTF-16 (LE)?

Comment: Well, because U+FEFF is a character and U+FFEF is not.  A zero-width space has the nice property that it has no effect on rendered text even when an app does not properly filter it or flubs by inserting BOMs in the middle of a text stream.  Very common bug.

Comment: On your "rather than U+EF BB BF for UTF-8": quite funny, because UTF8 does not need a "byte order mark". All values in an UTF8 encoded text are supposed to be exactly 1 byte long, so there is zero chance of getting your endianness wrong.

Comment: @RadLexus So UTF-8 doesn't need a BOM to indicate the endianness, while UTF-16 and UTF-32 does?

Comment: Yes. There is a quite lengthy article discussing all varieties on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I know, most machines using Intel CPUs are little-endian

Intel CPUs are not the only CPUs used in the world.  AMD, ARM, etc. And there are big-endian CPUs.

> why BOM is U+FE FF for UTF-16 (BE), rather than U+EF BB BF for UTF-8 or U+FF FE for UTF-16 (LE)?

`U+FEFF` is the Unicode codepoint designation.  `FE FF`, `EF BB BF`, `FF FE`, these are sequences of bytes instead.  `U+` only applies to Unicode codepoint designations, not bytes.

The numeric value of Unicode codepoint `U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` (which is its *official* designation, not `U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK`, though it is *also* used as a BOM) is `0xFEFF` (65279).

That codepoint value encoded in UTF-8 produces three 8-bit codeunit values `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`, which are not subject to any endian issues, which is why UTF-8 does not have separate LE and BE variants.

That same codepoint value encoded in UTF-16 produces one 16-bit codeunit value `0xFEFF`.  Because it is a multi-byte (16-bit) value, it is subject to endian when interpreted as two 8-bit bytes, hence the LE (`0xFF 0xFE`) and BE (`0xFE 0xFF`) variants.

It is not just the BOM that is effected.  All codeunits in a UTF-16 string are affected by endian.  The BOM helps a decoder know the endian used for the codeunits in the entire string.

UTF-32, which also uses multi-byte (32-bit) codeunits, is also subject to endian, and thus it also has LE and BE variants, and a 32-bit BOM to express that endian to decoders (`0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00` for LE, `0x00 0x00 0xFE 0xFF` for BE).  And yes, as you can probably guess, there is an ambiguity between the UTF-16LE BOM and the UTF-32LE BOM, if you don't know ahead of time which UTF you are dealing with.  A BOM is meant to identify the endian, hence the name "**Byte Order** Mark", not the particular encoding (though it is commonly used for that purpose).

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that `U+FFFE` is not a valid Unicode code point, which is why `U+FEFF` can be used as a byte order mark (otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish reliably). And "endian" should be "endianness".

Comment: I do see that U+FEFF was deprecated in Unicode 3.2 as a break character in favor of U+2060 WORD JOINER for that purpose. However, the Unicode spec does also say that if U+FEFF appears inside a string then it should still be treated as a breaker: "*Unicode 3.2 implementations should support this new character [U+2060], **but also support the ZWNBSP semantic of U+FEFF**.*"

Comment: Did you misread my comment? **`U+FEFF`** is a valid character (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE), and is used as a BOM. **`U+FFFE`** is *not* a valid character, or at least doesn't have a name assigned to it (see [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt, a 1.6MB text file) -- which is why **`U+FEFF`** can be used as a BOM. If you see **`U+FFFE`**, it's probably a byte-swapped BOM, and you need to change the endianness you're using to interpret the input. (And "endian" is an adjective; "endianness" is the corresponding noun.)

Comment: Yes, I misread your comment. And yes, if you read a 2-byte BOM into a 16-bit variable and get a valus of `0xFFFE` then the BOM is in the opposite endian than what you read it as.

Comment: Then is it OK to write `fputwc(L'\uFEFF', fp);` to add a BOM?

Answer (score 2):

> why BOM is U+FE FF for UTF-16 (BE)

It isn't. BOM is character number U+FEFF. There's no space, it's a single hexadecimal number, aka 65279. This definition does not depend on what sequence of bytes is used to represent that characters in any particular encoding.

It happens that the hexadecimal representation of the byte sequence that encodes the character(*) in UTF-16LE, `0xFE, 0xFF` has the same order of digits as the hexadecimal representation of the character number `U+FEFF`; this is just an artefact of big-endianness, it puts most-significant content on the left, same as humans do for big [hexa]decimal numbers.

(* and indeed any character in the Basic Multilingual Plane. It gets hairier when you go above this range as they no longer fit in two bytes.)